# Any way to detect if duration on countdown has ended in MomentJS

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, countdown

I got a countdown in VueJS and MomentJS using diff and duration methods from Moment.
I would like to detect when duration is 0 so I can clear the Interval of 1s.

Any way to do it? This is some part in my current code where I have the setInterval.

```
mounted: function () {
    this.date = this.$moment(this.date).utcOffset('-0300')
    this.difference = this.date.diff(this.today)
    this.duration = this.$moment.duration(this.difference)

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        this.duration = this.duration.subtract(1, 'seconds')

        if (/* validation if duration has ended */) {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }.bind(this), 1000)
```

I get I could validate each days(), hours(), minutes() and seconds() to be equal to 0 but it feels quite dirty to do such thing, I was wondering if there's any better way to validate this.

Also, isn't MomentJS months starting at index 0 so it goes from 0 to 11? Right now it's working from 1 to 12. I don't understand why.

Any help will be appreciated.